# Bootstrap - how to change active li color in dropdown navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am struggling with dropdown li active background color. 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVsgc.png)
How to change this "wiadomości" background color to not be gray color? 
Here is my code:

```
<li class="dzieci-link">
            <a href="#" class="linkor" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><font color="white">Wiadomości <span class="caret"></font></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="">Twoje wiadomości</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Wyślij wiadomość</a></li>
            </ul>
 </li>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work for you, assuming your using a normal BootStrap navbar without much alterations:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover {
    background-color: red;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Working FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/mcv0vj99/

When you click a dropdown, BootStrap adds an `open` class to the parent `li`, which might be overriding your previous attempts.

NOTE - you should place the above in your CSS file which is referenced AFTER BootStrap's CSS file, and/or append a parent child so you have a parent / child selector - IE - `.bodyclass .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a {}`

EDIT - a potential error in your code is that you seem to have ommited the class "`dropdown`" from the parent `li`. IE:

```
<li class="dzieci-link">
```

Should be:

```
<li class="dropdown dzieci-link">
```

Comment: It's not working in my case. I'm seeing that it works in your case but what to do now?

Comment: @forexknight Have you dramatically changed the BootStrap code for your project? Do you mind sharing more of your code please - the entire navbar would be ideal.

Comment: @forexknight Also, you seem to have removed the class "dropdown" from the parent li: `<li class="dzieci-link">` should be: `<li class="dropdown dzieci-link">`

Comment: I will try again tomorrow and write back if it is working! Thanks for your help! Anyway I have a question. Why If I use  .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
    background-color:blue;
  } It works, but when I use  .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
    background-color:blue;
  } it is not working. That's pretty werid.

Comment: It's still not working is here any other solution to fix it?

Comment: @forexknight Not at the moment - you can see my solution works, I use the same solution all the time in my projects but I think you must have a style somewhere which is overriding it. Is your custom CSS file referenced AFTER BootStrap CSS file?

Comment: Yes is it. Hmm but where. Anyway I think that Bootstrap is not quite cool afer that problem.

Comment: @forexknight Haha, BootStrap is cool - it can sometimes be difficult to override is all... For now, try adding !important after the properties, so: `background-color: red !important;` If that works, then you have a style somewhere causing an override...

Comment: That's impossible. I will paste the code within a moment!

Comment: @forexknight AHHHHH!!! Now I see the problem! Here's your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hmeqwzrd/1/. You'd wrapped your link in the navbar with: <font color="white">, so BootStrap's CSS style couldn't find it. Remove that and it works fine. You should style it with CSS, not inline.

Comment: Yes I saw it but it still doesn't work i delete the font-white hmm what is going on the active li is still with gray background. Hmm

Comment: It has to be something with my css. Hmm

Comment: @forexknight It must be something else then. Sorry I can't do much more as I can't see all your project code but it looks like you've got some rogue code in there somewhere that's causing the issue. You can see that my solution will work as long as you get the nav right though.

Comment: Finally it worked! I've solved it, the reason was that I had included bootstrap theme and normal bootstrap at the same time. The bootstrap theme was blocking the css, I don't know why!

Answer (score 1):

Work for me with Bootstrap 4.1.3

CSS :

```
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .show>.nav-link {
color: #ff0000;}
```

Replace .navbar-light with your own navbar style, eg .navbar-default if you use it

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<li class="dzieci-link">
            <a href="#" class="linker mycustomcolor" data-toggle="dropdown" 
               role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
               <font color="white">Wiadomości <span class="caret"></span></font></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="">Twoje wiadomości</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Wyślij wiadomość</a></li>
            </ul>
 </li>
```

CSS:

```
.mycustomcolor {
 background-color:blue !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this worked for me:

```
.dropdown-menu>.active>a{
background-color: #f5af01;
color: #000000;
}
```